# How to index a pandas DataFrame element in last column based on criteria being met in two other columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

A pandas dataframe has 4 columns:

```
df.columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'question', 'answer']
```

How do I index a single entry of the `'answer'` column, by indexing the dataframe based on criteria being met for the first columns?

i.e.:

```
df['col1'=='apple' and 'col2'=='guitar'].answer
```

Answer (score 1):

You can select values after filtering, but not recommended, because if set values similar way possible [warning](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#evaluation-order-matters):

```
s = df.loc[(df['col1']=='apple') & (df['col2']=='guitar')].answer
```

Better way is use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for filter by mask and by column name:

```
s = df.loc[(df['col1']=='apple') & (df['col2']=='guitar'), 'answer']
```

Or using [`DataFrame.query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
s = df.query("col1=='apple' and col2=='guitar'").answer
```

Output is one or more values in `Series`, if need first one to scalar:

```
first = s.iat[0]
```

If need solution working also if no match:

```
first  = next(iter(s), 'no match')
```